# Django - how to pass a value from an existing HTML form to a list view

Tags: django

I have an existing HTML form (text field + button) but have no idea how to pass an input value to a list view.

**Update:**

**book/home.html:**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="{% url 'book:search' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <input style="font-size: 12px; width: 200px" class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Book Name" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**book/models:**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=191, unique=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, allow_unicode=True)

    pub_date = models.DateField()

    ............
```

**book/views:**

```
class SearchResultView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'book/search.html'
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if search:
            queryset.filter(title__icontains=search)
        return queryset


class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'book/detail.html'
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

**book/urls:**

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('search/', views.SearchResultView.as_view(), name='search')
]
```

**book/templates/search.html (just for testing):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> here we go </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error on browser:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for search functionality you can use `GET` request instead of `POST`. To send form data to the specific view use `action` attribute. Also you need to add `name` attribute for `input` element:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="{% url 'view_urlname' %}">
    <input style="font-size: 12px; width: 200px" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Book Name" name="search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

To fetch form data in the view use `self.request.GET`:

```
class SearchResultView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'book/search.html'
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if search:
            queryset.filter(filedname_contains=search)
        return queryset
```

Comment: yeah that makes sense. but it is saying `Page not found (404) No book found matching the query`. The filed in book is called 'title', so I wrote `queryset.filter(title__contains='search')`. I tried single underscore and double underscore, they both didn't work.

Comment: And that error `Raised by: book.views.BookDetailView`. It was raised by another view, but that view is working fine.

Comment: @Jinx try `icontains`. Also it should be `search` not `'search'`. Without quotes: `queryset.filter(title__icontains=search)`.

Comment: still not working. And in book/urls - `path('search/', views.SearchResultView.as_view(), name='search')`, just tell you in case.

Comment: @jinx swap detail view and search view in urlpattern. Detail view's pattern is too common and triggered by /search/ url.

Comment: so the order of patterns should be from simple to complex?

Comment: @Jinx yes you should put most common pattern at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a custom queryset and show only the filter queryset instead of the full one, you can overwrite the `get_queryset()` function and get the form input by accessing `self.request.POST`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        book_name = self.request.POST.get('book_name', '')
        return Book.objects.filter(name=book_name)  # i'm assuming that in your Book model the name field if called 'name'
```

Then, you just have to be sure that the input has a name like this:

```
<input name="book_name" style="font-size: 12px; width: 200px" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Book Name" aria-label="Search">
```